# Whats the max number of containers that can be run in a Pod?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I understand that a pod can have multiple containers. But, I am trying to find if there is a max limit on the number of containers within a pod. I have googled around, but could not find an answer.

Comment: Why are you asking?  Remember that every container in a pod runs on the same node, and you can't independently stop or restart containers; usual best practice is to run one container in a pod, with additional containers only for things like an Istio network-proxy sidecar.

Comment: @DavidMaze to satiate my  desire to learn and know!

Comment: I expect, from experience with other Kubernetes object types, that you will encounter a limit on the maximum size Pod specification that the Kubernetes API can process and store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No limit - as long as the node can satisfy the resource requirements

After further research I have discovered the following:

[Cgroup In Brief](https://medium.com/geekculture/layer-by-layer-cgroup-in-kubernetes-c4e26bda676c)

> Cgroups, short for Control Groups, is provided by the Linux kernel. It
> is applied to restrict, record, and isolate the physical resources
> (CPU, memory, i/o) used by process groups. Cgroups can respectively
> form a tree structure composed of multiple sub cgroups, according to
> different resource types, so as to uniformly control the overall
> resource usage from top to bottom.

1. The pod creates a [cgroups hirarchy](https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/containers-vs-pods/)
2. Containers in the pods share the cgroup hierarchy
3. cgroup allows a container to take turn and use the compute resources
4. So, the number of containers within a pod depends solely on the resource availability on that node

Answer (score 12):

AFAIK, there is no such pod-specific limit. Though there are some cluster-specific criteria (k8s v1.21) like:

- No more than 110 pods per node
- No more than 5000 nodes
- No more than 150000 total pods
- No more than 300000 total containers

**N.B.**: Since a pod can be scheduled to a single node, you are also limited by node resources (ie. cpu, memory). So, when you increase the number of containers of a pod, make sure that your node has enough resources to accommodate your pod.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add kubernetes doc link for the above answer https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/cluster-large/